# Spring upgrade 2.6.3 property issue in xml configuration

Tags: spring

Recently we upgraded our apis to spring 2.6.3. Just after upgrade we noticed that spring xml beans which was reading properties from application yml file is not able to read values. If i downgrade my spring jars, the same bean xml works

Comment: There is far too little information in this question. Upgrading from which version, what error do you get etc.

Comment: We upgraded from springboot  2.4.8 to spring boot 2.6.3. The property is passed as empty in spring xml. Earlier in 2.4.8 the property was passed as it was present in application yml file

Comment: Still far too little information. You are skipping 2.5 and I suspect you just changed the version and didn't bother to read the upgrading to 2.5 and 2.6 documentation. Also please include that information in your question not only in comments. Add some code and configuration.